# pydantic validation errors when using tradier-python on Windows 11 OS

Tags: validation, pydantic

I am having wired problem. I am migrating from a old server to a new one (windows 10 to windows 11). Both installed with Anaconda distro and all packages are updated to latest version.

I am using tradier-python package to automate my trades. The code works fine on Windows 10 env but fails on Windows 11 with pydantic validation errors.

Below is my code and the error.

Has anyone faced similar issue ??

Here is my sample code

```
import os
from tradier_python import TradierAPI

token = <my token>
account_id = <my_acctID>
t = TradierAPI(token=token, default_account_id=account_id)

## BUY ORDER 
symbol = "TSLA"
option_symbol = "TSLA230825C00245000"
option_side = "buy_to_open"
quantity = 1
order_type = "MARKET"
stop = 1.5
duration = "GTC"


order = t.order_option(    
    symbol=symbol,
    option_symbol=option_symbol,
    side=option_side,
    quantity=quantity,
    order_type=order_type,
    duration=duration,
    stop_price=stop)

### No error on the earlier call .

## STOP ORDER 
symbol = "TSLA"
option_symbol = "TSLA230825C00245000"
option_side = "sell_to_close"
quantity = 1
order_type = "STOP"
stop = 1.5
duration = "GTC"

order = t.order_option(    
    symbol=symbol,
    option_symbol=option_symbol,
    side=option_side,
    quantity=quantity,
    order_type=order_type,
    duration=duration,
    stop_price=stop)
    
 ### The order is placed but gets a error pydantic validation errors on the response
```

Here is the error

```
ValidationError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 38
---> 38 order = t.order_option(    
     39     symbol=symbol,
     40     option_symbol=option_symbol,
     41     side=option_side,
     42     quantity=quantity,
     43     order_type=order_type,
     44     duration=duration,
     45     stop_price=stop)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tradier_python\tradier_api.py:281, in TradierAPI.order_option(self, symbol, option_symbol, side, quantity, order_type, duration, limit_price, stop_price, tag, account_id)
    265 def order_option(
    266     self,
    267     symbol: str,
   (...)
    276     account_id: str = None,
    277 ) -> OrderDetails:
    278     """
    279     Place an order to trade a single option.
    280     """
--> 281     return self.order(
    282         order_class="option",
    283         symbol=symbol,
    284         option_symbol=option_symbol,
    285         side=side,
    286         quantity=quantity,
    287         order_type=order_type,
    288         duration=duration,
    289         limit_price=limit_price,
    290         stop_price=stop_price,
    291         tag=tag,
    292         account_id=account_id,
    293     )

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tradier_python\tradier_api.py:232, in TradierAPI.order(self, order_class, symbol, order_type, duration, quantity, side, limit_price, stop_price, tag, account_id, option_symbol, option_symbol_0, side_0, quantity_0, option_symbol_1, side_1, quantity_1, option_symbol_2, side_2, quantity_2, option_symbol_3, side_3, quantity_3)
    230 params = {k: v for k, v in params.items() if v is not None}
    231 data = self.post(url, params)
--> 232 res = OrderAPIResponse(**data)
    233 if res.errors:
    234     raise TradierOrderError(res.errors.error_list)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pydantic\main.py:159, in BaseModel.__init__(__pydantic_self__, **data)
    157 # `__tracebackhide__` tells pytest and some other tools to omit this function from tracebacks
    158 __tracebackhide__ = True
--> 159 __pydantic_self__.__pydantic_validator__.validate_python(data, self_instance=__pydantic_self__)

ValidationError: 2 validation errors for OrderAPIResponse
order.id
  Input should be a valid string [type=string_type, input_value=7598205, input_type=int]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.2/v/string_type
errors
  Field required [type=missing, input_value={'order': {'id': 7598205,...ffe-8a0c-294fbad1aee9'}}, input_type=dict]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.2/v/missing"
```